# How to call for bloginfo inside function in functions.php?

Tags: urls, admin-bar, bloginfo

I am new to WordPress and PHP, so I have this question:

I want to add a Link to the "New Post" for a Custom Post Type I implemented. But it will only let me put static links, connected to my localhost test installation.

How do I add a non-static URL right there, like a `bloginfo('wpurl')` that it will actually read out?

This is what I want:

```
 function wp_admin_bar_new_item(){
        global $wp_admin_bar;
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
            'id'=>'wp-admin-bar-new-item',
            'title'=>__("Kunstwerk hinzuf&uuml;gen"),

            'href'=>//Here it I want a link to my Custom Post Type
            ));
    }
```

And this is what I tried that didn't work:

```
function wp_admin_bar_new_item(){
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
        'id'=>'wp-admin-bar-new-item',
        'title'=>__("Kunstwerk hinzuf&uuml;gen"),

        'href'=>'bloginfo("wpurl");/../../wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=albertis-kunstwerke'
        ));
}
```

and this is what is working with my localhost, but I don't want it to be static.

```
function wp_admin_bar_new_item(){
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
        'id'=>'wp-admin-bar-new-item',
        'title'=>__("Kunstwerk hinzuf&uuml;gen"),
        'href'=>'http://localhost:8888/test/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=albertis-kunstwerke'
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
'href'=> admin_url("post-new.php?post_type=albertis-kunstwerke")
```